# Any issues with Firebase Dynamic Links in iOS 13?

Tags: ios13, firebase-dynamic-links, smart-app-banner

Is Firebase Dynaic Links (to the App if installed or to Store if app has to be downloaded) working fine in iOS ?

Usecase: We have a webpage (with user context) and we want to have a link to our Mobile App (Launch App if available or direct to download & install from store). After install & upon launch the mobile app should be able to get the user context that was passed from the webpage.

Android: URL Schema can be used if users are viewing the webpage from Android device Browser
iOS: Smart App Banner can be used if users are viewing the webpage from iOS device Browser

I also have usecase where users are in Desktop Browser. We want to provide a QR code , which upon scanned by the mobile, should be able to launch App or App/Playstore. Smart App Banners cannot be used in this usecase.

We are exploring Firebase Dynamic Link but, also see articles mentioning about its bug when it comes to iOS 13+ devices.

> Has anyone implemented Firebase Dynamic Link with iOS 13+ Device ? any
>   issues faced/reported ?

Comment: I have similar issue on ios13 but cant tell yet if its only for ios13.

Comment: could you share the exact nature of the issue you are facing ?

Comment: apparently my issue was not related to ios13. I have it working now. you can debug your dynamic link by appending `?d=1` in the url.

Answer (score 1):

You can find open issues here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/labels/api%3A%20dynamiclinks - which, incidentially, at the time of writing, [does report flakyness](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/6393).